# rake db:migrate postgreSQL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I finally got the gem pg to install.  Now when I go to migrate the database I get the following:

```
$ rake db:migrate
(in c:/rubyDev/bsbaslic)
rake aborted!
no such file to load -- 1.9/pg_ext
c:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/pg-0.10.0/lib/pg.rb:10:in `require'
c:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/pg-0.10.0/lib/pg.rb:10:in `<top (required)>'
c:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:64:in `require'
c:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:64:in `block (2 levels) in require'
c:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:62:in `each'
c:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:62:in `block in require'
c:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:51:in `each'
c:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:51:in `require'
c:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.3/lib/bundler.rb:112:in `require'
c:/rubyDev/bsbaslic/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
<internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
<internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
c:/rubyDev/bsbaslic/Rakefile:4:in `<top (required)>'
c:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:2373:in `load'
c:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:2373:in `raw_load_rakefile'
c:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:2007:in `block in load_rakefile'
c:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:2058:in `standard_exception_handling'
c:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:2006:in `load_rakefile'
c:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:1991:in `run'
c:/Ruby192/bin/rake:31:in `<main>'
```

Does anybody have any ideas as to what it is looking for?  I have a pg_ext.so file in the same directory as pg.rb.

Comment: What version of the Postgres gem (pg) are you running?

Answer (score 1):

Windows programs cannot load `.so` files - they load `.dll` files instead. You need a build of `pg` compiled for Windows, or you need to be running Ruby from within a Linuxy environment such as msys or cygwin.

Comment: I am running from msys.  I could not get "gem install pg" to work within the regular command prompt.  Any other ideas?

Comment: When you run "gem install" what specifically happens? Please add that to your question.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in your version of pg gem. There is a special version for windows pg 0.9.0.
In order to have it workingon windows:

1. uninstall the current pg 0.10.0
2. install pg as follows: **gem install pg --version=0.9.0 -- --with-pg-config=/short/path/to/postresql/bin** 
   (To get short path you can simply change directory to PostgrSQL bin and then type **command** in cmd, it will automaticaly change path to a short verison)
3. Then edit your project Gemfile in order to use correct pg gem version (0.9.0)

And that's it.

Good Luck

Comment: 10 months on, should later versions now work? I need pg and activerecord-postgis-adapter. activerecord-postgis-adapter seems to require at least 0.10.0.